# Pgfplots - Labeling Regions

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to draw chart which indicates different regions of stability/instability in all the areas demarcated by the different curves.

How can I manually put in Roman numerals or letters on different parts of the graph?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ticks=none,
        xtick={-10,-9,...,10},   
        xmin=-2,
        xmax=2,
        xlabel={$\alpha$},
        axis x line=middle,
        ytick={-10,-9,...,10},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=10,
        ylabel={$s$},
        axis y line=middle,
        no markers,
        samples=100,
        domain=-10:10,
        restrict y to domain=-20:20,
        width = 6in ]
    \addplot[green,samples=400] (x,{-1/x});
    \addplot[blue,samples=400, domain=-1:1] (x,{1/(1+2*x)});
   \addplot[red,samples=400, domain=-1:1] (x,{-4*x/(1+x)^2}) node[pos=0.5, pin=-135:{$\frac{-4\alpha}{(1+\alpha^2)}$}] {};
%       \end{axis}
    \draw[cyan] (axis cs:1,0) -- (axis cs: 1,10) node[pos=1, pin = -30: {\tiny $\alpha=1$}] {};
    \draw[cyan] (axis cs:-1,0) -- (axis cs: -1,10) node[pos=1, pin = -120: {\tiny $\alpha=-1$}] {};
    \draw [draw=black, fill=white, thin] (axis cs: -0.5, 8) circle (1.0pt);
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Not sure about your question. Is is something like `\path (axis cs: -0.5,1.5) node {I};` what you want?

Comment: Don't understand your questions. It seems that you know how to label a function. Same idea applies for other labels. Sure, there are approaches, e.g., Ignasi suggested.

Comment: @Ignasi Or simply \node at (axis cs:#,#) {I};

Comment: Hi!  Sorry for the confusion, Jesse's answer is the one I was looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given your code and in addition to you have known, I tried several examples to give an ideal on how to give a label.

1. You may need to adjust your axis cs x,y to suit your needs.
2. You can define as many other style to suit your needs.

[image]

Code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{                                         % for optional style
every pin/.style={fill=yellow, circle, scale=1, pin distance=10pt, inner sep=0pt,  font=\footnotesize},
small dot/.style={fill=black, circle, scale=0.3}} % user defined coordinate
\begin{axis}[ticks=none,
        xtick={-10,-9,...,10},   
        xmin=-2,
        xmax=2,
        xlabel={$\alpha$},
        axis x line=middle,
        ytick={-10,-9,...,10},
        ymin=0,
        ymax=10,
        ylabel={$s$},
        axis y line=middle,
        no markers,
        samples=100,
        domain=-10:10,
        restrict y to domain=-20:20,
        width = 6in ]
    \addplot[green,samples=400] (x,{-1/x});
    \addplot[blue,samples=400, domain=-1:1] (x,{1/(1+2*x)});
    \addplot[red,samples=400, domain=-1:1] (x,{-4*x/(1+x)^2})   node[pos=0.5, pin=-135:{$\frac{-4\alpha}{(1+\alpha^2)}$}] {};
\draw[draw=black, fill=white, thin] (axis cs: -0.5, 8) circle (1.0pt);

% ---These are examples to show how ----------------
\node[small dot, pin=above:here1] at (axis cs: 0.5,3){};
\node[small dot, label=left:here2] at (axis cs: -1,4){};
\node[small dot, label={[red]left:here3}] at (axis cs: -1.5,5){};
\node[coordinate, pin =above:{\tiny $\alpha=1$}] at (axis cs: 1,1){};
\node[coordinate, pin =above:{\tiny $\alpha=-1$}] at (axis cs: -1,1) {};
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
```